# How to restore .bak file in oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have back up file for oracle 11g.(.bak file)
How to restore .bak file in Oracle 11g.Please, anyone, help me.I am new in Oracle.

Comment: What is a `.bak` file? What utility created it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with a .bak file the best utility to restore would be oracle rman. You can google oracle rman backup and recovery concepts , lots of online resources to help you out.